# How to decode a hex packet in Python 3.7

Tags: python, sockets, networking, decode

I made a raw packet sniffer in Python 3.7, and I can get source addr,port,ttl,etc... But I can't decode the packet. Can anyone help me on this?

Raw Packet Data:

```
b'\x01\x01\x06\x00&H\xf0o\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00L    fA\xd0h{\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x    00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x    00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
    00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x    00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00c\x82Sc5\x01\x03=\x07\x01LfA
\xd0h{2\x04\n\xe8\xfc96\x04\n\xe8\x01\x869\x02\x05\xdc<\x0cdhcpcd-5.5.6\x0c\x18android-d3cc48d8b902bbdc7\t\x01!\x03\x06\x0f\x1c3:;\xff'
```

Sorry about how it looks stackoverflow is weird pasting things in.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you mean with *"decode the packet"*. If you want to have the payload shown in a useful way for example like wireshark does then you have to implement the protocol or use an existing implementation. But the details depend on the specific protocol.